# How to give customized answers with LUIS and Azure Bot

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, hybrid, aws-chatbot

I am working on creating a new hybrid chatbot. Together, we defined that the most frequently asked questions for this chatbot should be order status, stock status, and shipment tracking questions.

- For example:

What is the current status of my order **[Order ID]**?

What is the stock of **[Product ID]**?

etc,...

With these above-mentioned questions, I want the bot to give a customized link with the given entities **[Order ID]** and **[Product ID]**.

To be more precise, if the question is "*What is the stock of SA1234?*", the chatbot should be able to recognize that the question is about the stock, then it can extract the string "SA1234" and give the respective link to the stock of SA1234.

Have anyone worked on a Chatbot designed for the same purpose, using LUIS and Microsoft Azure bot?
If yes, can you provide me with more info, documentation, or code source for this?

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement this is possible in Azure chatbot using LUIS app !!

**Create a LUIS application in LUIS Portal**

Click on the "New app" and give the meaningful name for the requirement.

[image]

**Create intent in LUIS App**

We need to identify a specific information about a category then in LUIS "intent" is the special term using for this implementation.

[image]

> The chatbot should be able to recognize that the question is about the
> stock ?

Yes!! This is possible, You should create a category or *"intent"* in LUIS application E.g "stock" name as intent. Then add couple of questions or utterances related to Stock in "stock" intent.

[image]

> If the question is "What is the stock of SA1234? can extract the string "SA1234" ?

Yes, Here you need to create LUIS Regex entity with proper regular expression for stock extraction ("SA123").

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Reference :**

1. [Luis entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/reference-entity-regular-expression?tabs=V2)
2. [LUIS App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-create-app)

Comment: One further comment, I would recommend using Machine Learned entity instead of regex, especially since something like part number may not follow an easily-definable format. ML entity will take into account the context of the utterance to identify entities even if they don't follow a prior pattern.

Comment: @billoverton agree with your point ML also one suggestion based on the business requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Anyway, what I actually was looking for is after this. I am developing a chatbot on Visual Studio in C#.
I am wondering how can we extract an entity from the question to a specific attribute  so that it is understood by the bot and the bot can give the respective answer